# Add various objects and keys to nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I would like to create a NSDictionary with the objects and keys, as example below

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                                                   forKeys:keys];
```

but I need to add multiple registers, like:

```
code=1
description=John

code=2
description=Paul

code=3
description=Peter
.
.
.

exactly what I need, an NSDictionary like a json structure:
{
"people": [
{ "code":"1" , "name":"John" }, 
{ "code":"2" , "name":"Smith" }, 
{ "code":"3" , "name":"Jones" }
]
}
```

Comment: Define: "multiple registers". Perhaps you need a dictionary of dictionaries. SHow what you want in JSON format.

Comment: This question is very confusing. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: Is this what you want to end up with: `@{@"key1":@{@"code":@2,@"description":@"Paul"}, @"key2":@{@"code":@3,@"description":@"Peter"}, ...}?`  if so (or if not..) don't answer in a comment, update your question

Comment: Remember, you can always embed an array inside a dictionary:  `dictionary = @{@"code":@[@"John",@"Paul",@"Peter"]};`

Comment: The 'JSON' you've posted isn't valid JSON, nor close enough for me to understand your intent with any confidence.

Comment: If "exactly what you need" is what you show, why don't you just build it.  A dictionary containing one entry named "people" which has as it's value an array containing 3 dictionaries, each containing "code" and "name" entries.  Why is that hard??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the values are klnown at compile time the structure can be created with literals:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{
    @"people": @[
        @{ @"code":@"1" , @"name":@"John" },
        @{ @"code":@"2" , @"name":@"Smith" },
        @{ @"code":@"3" , @"name":@"Jones" }
    ]
};
NSLog(@"d: %@", d);
```

NSLog output:

```
dictionary: {
    people =     (
                {
            code = 1;
            name = John;
        },
                {
            code = 2;
            name = Smith;
        },
                {
            code = 3;
            name = Jones;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks. Your suggestion worked perfectly for me.

Comment: it's help full but....how to create dynamic? code & name are not fix...

Comment: code and name sometimes 4... sometimes 3 ...please help me

Comment: Consider asking a question with a a complete description.

Comment: sometime like this dictionary: {
    people =     (
                  {
                      code = 1;
                      name = John;
                  },
                
                  );
}

Comment: A dictionary containing one entry named "people" which has as it's value an array containing 3 dictionaries, each containing "code" and "name" entries.  but I want containing dictionaries dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need to create NSArray of NSDictionarys.

```
NSArray *keys1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"code", @"description", nil];
NSArray *objects1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"Paul", nil];

NSDictionary *register1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects1 forKeys:keys1]

NSArray *keys2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"code", @"description", nil];
NSArray *objects2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"Tom", nil];

NSDictionary *register2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects2 forKeys:keys2];

NSArray *keys3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"code", @"description", nil];
NSArray *objects3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"Robin", nil];

NSDictionary *register3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects3 forKeys:keys3];
NSArray *registers = @[register1, register2, register3];
NSLog(@"%@", registers);
```

Comment: Literal syntax for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]` is `@2`

Comment: Literal syntax for `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"code", @"description", nil]` is `@[:@"code", @"description"]`